# JComboBox: change one selection item to italic

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to change one selection item in **existing** jcombobox (items are already added) to italic? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The rendering of elements for a `JComboBox` is controlled via the `ListCellRenderer`. Take a look at [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more details

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one helps you :)

You just have to add the ListCellRenderer to your ComboBox.

```
class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel
                       implements ListCellRenderer {
    . . .
    public ComboBoxRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
    }

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                                   JList list,
                                   Object value,
                                   int index,
                                   boolean isSelected,
                                   boolean cellHasFocus) {
    //Get the selected index. (The index param isn't
    //always valid, so just use the value.)
    int selectedIndex = ((Integer)value).intValue();

    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    } else {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }

    //Set the icon and text.  If icon was null, say so.
    ImageIcon icon = images[selectedIndex];
    String pet = petStrings[selectedIndex];
    setIcon(icon);
    if (icon != null) {
        setText(pet);
        setFont(list.getFont()); //HERE YOU ALSO HAVE TO SET THE COLOR OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT
    } else {
        setUhOhText(pet + " (no image available)",
                    list.getFont());
    }

    return this;
}
. . .
```

}